# Layout Designing in XML Android

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I want to make a layout as given in the image below, but I am unable to make same as it is showing in the image. I have to align the buttons exactly same as that they are given in the image attached. Here is my code how I am making it and I am not able to get the alignment exact as displayed.

I have added my resources also (buttons and background) [image]

[image]

```
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_home_driver"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="38dp"
        android:background="@drawable/driverbtn" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonPassengerHomeScreen"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button_home_driver"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
        android:background="@drawable/passengerbtn" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I am not able to align the buttons along the Tilted Black Divider Screen.

Anyone please help me in the same. (Both the buttons should start from the Black Boundary as shown in the image)

[image]

Comment: You need to try with using `FrameLayout`.

Comment: @GrIsHu I too have the same problem with one of my layouts. Can you please explain a bit. If you can

Comment: Perhaps you could show what is actually happening so others can see what the error is

Comment: @GauravArora show what is your problem ?

Comment: What you've posted is a background image and the button image, not what it looks like when it's wrong...